# What does the "hash" do in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have come across this in the android documentation

`CameraDevice#createCaptureSession`

and

`CameraDevice#createReprocessableCaptureSession`

What does the "hash" symbol mean?

Comment: That isn't valid Kotlin. I guess they've used it in the documentation to just refer to a method in a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Kotlin. Looks like they have used to refer specific part of sections in the Android developer documentation.

For example

```
CameraDevice#createCaptureSession
```

This will route you to the `createCaptureSession` method section in their documentation.